# migrate svn to git with svn external

Tags: git, svn, version-control, tortoisegit

I am new to git, I am now want to leave subversion svn and use git. Is there any method can move svn to git with all its svn  externals with tortoisegit. I have tried the function git clone but it doesn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I used the recipe in http://patrickbougie.com/2013/03/18/convert-svn-to-git-repository/ recently and it did the trick.

In general, though, I prefer changing the build to refer to external dependencies, rather than include the source code at the right point. If you're using Maven, then Maven modules are designed for just that.